# Why is RSA considered safe?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, algorithm-design, keys

Why is RSA safe, using this algorithm to calculate $d$ as the private key?
$$e\cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)},$$
where $e$ is part of the public key and $n$ is also part of the public key, so there is only one variable the attacker doesn't know, and that is $d$?  Why can't they can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to calculate it?  Even if they can't, why is it considered safe?

Comment: The attacker doesn't know $\varphi(n)$

Comment: But CodesinChaos the attacker can calculate φ(n) right ? They is a lot of website help calculate it online , huh ?

Comment: Calculating $\varphi(n)$ is equivalent (-> as hard as) factoring $n$, which is "easy" for small values of $n$ (so websites can do it), but infeasible for cryptographically relevant values of $n$.

Comment: @user9119852 It seems you have created two accounts, you might want to get them merged. [Have a look at our help center.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Yeah thank you @SEJPM ! I accidentally create one for mobile one for computer , thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *theoretically* anyone can compute $\varphi(n)$ from $n$ and thus recover $d$ from $e$. This should be read as "given any $n$, it takes a finite amount of time to compute $\varphi(n)$".

More practically, "computing $\varphi(n)$ given $n$" and "factoring $n$" are equivalently hard. That is, if you can efficiently compute $\varphi(n)$ you can also efficiently factor $n$ and vice versa.

Now, if $n$ is sufficiently small, we can easily factor it and thus compute $\varphi(n)$ (which is what websites do), but as $n$ reaches cryptographically relevant values, it becomes infeasible (using current technology) to factor $n$ and thus to recover $\varphi(n)$.